# How can i use appendTo and insertBefore properly

Tags: jquery, insert, append, appendto

With the append button i add elements to the same class. 
I want the append button and delete button beneath the appended elements,
but when i use insertBefore, the Toggle function only toggles the buttons visibility.

You can check out what i mean here;

click add a box and start appending

http://www.jsfiddle.net/myd3k/

replace appendTo with inserBefore and toggle the visibility.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `prependTo`

http://www.jsfiddle.net/myd3k/1/